# Receiving base64 string in web api

Tags: web, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to receive a base64 string (which is an image) in my web api web service.

The issue I am having is with the length of the string, is there a way I can set the limit of of incoming strings to allow for a string of a massive size? The string has already been encoded for url use. From what I can tell this is my issue. Right now if I call the function it gives me an 404 error. However if I remove the base64string and put in just a normal string it works.

This is my function

```
    public int userLogin(string identifier, string name, string hometown, string photo)
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        ds = new DataSet();
        command = new SqlCommand("p_userLogin", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userInfo", identifier);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hometown", hometown);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photo);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand = command;
        da.Fill(ds);
        int userID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
        return userID;
    }
```

And this is the base 64 string I am trying to send

```
%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD%2F%2FgAEKgD%2F4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIMbGNtcwIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAH3AABABkAAwApADlhY3NwQVBQTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLWxjbXMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAApkZXNjAAAA%2FAAAAF5jcHJ0AAABXAAAAAt3dHB0AAABaAAAABRia3B0AAABfAAAABRyWFlaAAABkAAAABRnWFlaAAABpAAAABRiWFlaAAABuAAAABRyVFJDAAABzAAAAEBnVFJDAAABzAAAAEBiVFJDAAABzAAAAEBkZXNjAAAAAAAAAANjMgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB0ZXh0AAAAAEZCAABYWVogAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLVhZWiAAAAAAAAADFgAAAzMAAAKkWFlaIAAAAAAAAG%2BiAAA49QAAA5BYWVogAAAAAAAAYpkAALeFAAAY2lhZWiAAAAAAAAAkoAAAD4QAALbPY3VydgAAAAAAAAAaAAAAywHJA2MFkghrC%2FYQPxVRGzQh8SmQMhg7kkYFUXdd7WtwegWJsZp8rGm%2FfdPD6TD%2F%2F%2F%2FbAEMABQMEBAQDBQQEBAUFBQYHDAgHBwcHDwsLCQwRDxISEQ8RERMWHBcTFBoVEREYIRgaHR0fHx8TFyIkIh4kHB4fHv%2FbAEMBBQUFBwYHDggIDh4UERQeHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHv%2FCABEIADwAZAMAIgABEQECEQH%2FxAAcAAABBAMBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQMEBwIFBgj%2FxAAYAQADAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQMCBP%2FEABgBAAMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAwIE%2F9oADAMAAAERAhEAAAG3QMTBFYY5alPBmA1LrcjxmXOxgKQAAAQEQQRHkMrWkgTVn3RGV6Nz2YFOQEAXAR5CHywdvHqbimW5qpU2HU1O5isaR9TJSdjax0iQETnpgrVY1xblUtZOsSR7mDcLkI%2Bdtb0WNq6Fd8N63KeI%2F8QAIRAAAgICAQUBAQAAAAAAAAAAAgMBBAAFBhAREhMwFCD%2F2gAIAQAAAQUC%2FkpgR9UNCKaAy7WU1fGXlE%2FDYWlpwthInOx8sPZ1pbou5bn4WIiVlArKuqGYaFjmmCFW%2Fg%2BO6S9hwMyEMPyygiFB8H2EVxZdhETdKwSR8Q0u9q3F%2FwAss11za5Lr1Ff5M5sMf7D1tit%2BWCoxm9upXREhzV8jfVGlvdbaH91TryKxNZn7QwXgYLcIwbRyWl5bA%2FJ%2FUbTxjpy8yXR97u0OdlZrSswsMYIiBWXkUvd2h7s97s97s%2F%2FEAB4RAAEEAgMBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAhEgAyEQEhMx%2F9oACAECEQE%2FAeWgQssRUfVqFkLQLMdpPf2OqyvU0%2F%2FEABwRAAICAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABESECECASMf%2FaAAgBAREBPwHbRj1IvvMDRgiN2WemWWWf%2F8QAMhAAAQMCAQkHAwUAAAAAAAAAAQACAxEhEgQiMTIzQWFxkhATIDBCUVIjYqE0Q4GC0f%2FaAAgBAAAGPwLwlx0BYpRnOvyWrVFuEKXI3%2Bi7fJZE%2B3e2xekc1oq3g1Yg0Bn32XdElrvwnu3YD5Ir7oGjiB7BPpaprnNRqGurwVIxc63LyXU3XQdE4r6jgrLFbE4eTWeZkY%2B4ovhHeQONWOCoFiduTYpHCGfRhOg8vFR80bTxKLYyZiN40LDk%2BGEc6lF8kuJx3kpsL5o81raX4f7VWmiH9k4RysLn5ooVrBCOVwnjHyNx%2FKtlDY3fF5ov1MXV2ySgVNKJ1cmZRxBogWsgizw6laaAv2HX9Tr89CpGyCww1BufxwQb3VvdYfj4KCV3bHgOHE%2B5C2r%2BpbWTqUTTLJQvA1lqhOIa2w9kXGZ9z8ltpOpbaTqW2k6ltpOpf%2F%2FEACcQAQACAQMCBgIDAAAAAAAAAAEAESExQVEQkSBhcYGhwdHhMPDx%2F9oACAEAAAE%2FIfC4NBbMUtdjRse0YWj5SUimsVHjXf8AF5P4LlC3Jbj1XvLA4ZrLl%2BY1Lxq1ft%2BZaHjCl9xGZzlJvk8T14gYPGEjh0IbszAnB5IXsw2alkmQv60%2BvCvgZWrBMSrgCPX2pUz3KD3YFp1uMa6k9OSJcbAgA4OO8qhjiAz0Zek3tEHcfXVl9PIfAkwdwtDuY8TnnydpuixsrBEqqx0TcHMF6Jhng5QdXtA5%2BSYNlBhvL8p5geZfhn%2BJly4JPSHzSbpscMI7Yvf%2B6Sth6gZDi7zdw6Zhbidk6tNcMJaVL90dzvCsVtjdR8zAr3nlLgwbUHn02g5c2Q0DvMN%2BdKf3Izcqy0uXTirSZIIT2S7xRaUO00OU%2FdEf2iY%2FsT%2F%2F2gAMAwAAARECEQAAEP8AnYN%2BoCoX5k0IxmM%2F7BlVolzfNjP%2FxAAaEQEAAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAABABEhEDEg%2F9oACAECEQE%2FEIPAUuBY%2BKjAXA0imzXztyoRE7MjwdTJdTJMqIOS%2Bf%2FEACARAAIABQUBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABEBEhMeEgcZGh8EH%2F2gAIAQERAT8QiwRp1hKLsOqYregkJ%2FsCnMbIlBeeQ6bd4HMt7gSlt3g294Ni5wf%2FxAAnEAEAAgIABgICAgMAAAAAAAABABEhMUFRYXGBkRDwIKGxwdHh8f%2FaAAgBAAABPxD8bHBvyAtgSxubWaeyjq3OWmhRcWa5BGuE702QdPYj5fh%2BWLBlL3GAokoQq7dXgYYJuyUWKCqNrMBct19ib7rYxnGmY9RPIjrFx7qNJlNYUH8x%2FB3OmW8%2FjJkUoBss3jSnmAoWwqwwvHHq6hStcYl5NWiZyjeWGrZBwArVeX3DtqbgEUuQIPEflgkW35Ciyo7Zf1cIFq8yPv8AzGvE029aczugohlJgKoQa78%2FEfik06SiWQbYMy7BGLHsHL4gMPQBHKEsC1PEqUcDUxvtcBUBzdDnAkkL4UwK4bOJu%2Be%2Fhm0Uxt5VHo3t5%2B2IQxVlnJLe4J1imuUmbyK8C%2BssiZbu8VuFIDhX79QPiMEE2tf8QNTVZsL61sHKznGcZ7JWSigchks6B6VCjzgL6NBh8RtB77jjuODlgMIAlDSf1cGoiTwUbXGsNrdpqgAKcRoBCmkrYDTV3DM1O5T2Fd25g4SuNI9OxqACkmq5A4jCbarwqbiXHdl%2Fo8RcALYRTkcwgTUNq9x3BYURVZikFM1dPgiGZ1v%2FAHxRft94XAh3ojx6zGRwwGliiTcA5LTESZAtbwDiXeAq%2FwC8QFpj75gF%2Bn5hS%2Bn5n%2F%2FZ
```

Any input on this would be appreciated.

Comment: you're sending that in the URL? Not as a `POST` parameter?

Comment: No it is a post parameter.  I simply used the browser to test other instances of that string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you got the answer or not, because question had posted long time back.

I also faced same problem,resolved my issue using
below link may help you to find the answer @Ken

[ASP.NET Web API does not allow Lengthy base64 URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455166/asp-net-web-api-does-not-allow-lengthy-base64-uri)